# tidyr: filter by pairs of values in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyr

Say I have this data.frame of bad subjects:

```
df_bad = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), condition=c('fun', 'boring', 'boring'))
```

Subject 1 is bad in the "fun" condition and subjects 2 and 3 are bad in the "boring" condition. Now I have my data:

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), condition=rep(c('fun', 'boring'), times=3), score=rnorm(6))
```

How do I remove the rows of `df` that matches a pair of `id` AND `condition` in `df_bad` using `tidyr`? I.e., how do I end up with this data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), condition=c('boring', 'fun', 'fun'), score=df$score[c(2,3,5)])
```

Ideally, the solution should also work for triplets of values in `df_bad`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df, df_bad)
```