# Filter data frame based off two columns in other data frame

Tags: r

I'm sure the answer to this will be VERY similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52952162/4309821) but I just can't quite put it together.

I have two data frames.  One is the data frame I'm working on:

```
df<-structure(list(Username = c("hmaens", "pgcmann", "gsamse", "gsamse", 
"gsamse", "gamse"), Title = c("Pharmacy Resident PGY2", "Associate Professor of Pediatrics", 
"Regulatory Coordinator", "Regulatory Coordinator", "Regulatory Coordinator", 
"Regulatory Coordinator"), `User Role` = c("Investigational Pharmacist", 
"Principal Investigator", "Calendar Build", "Protocol Management", 
"Subject Management", "Regulatory")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and one is they key:

```
key<-structure(list(username = c("hmaens", "pgcmann", "gsamse", "gsamse", 
"gsamse", "gsamse"), training = c(0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to split my "df" data frame based on the "training" column in key.  I.e. my results would be a data frame called dfZero with the exact same columns from df that had everyone from key with a "0" in training.  And a separate data frame called dfOne with the 1's from key$training.

Comment: You could use `df %>% left_join(key, by=c("Username"="username")) %>% split(~training)`. That will give you a list with the two separate data.frames.

Comment: What of the other usernames? `gsame` is not present in `key`, so that `training` is `NA`.

Comment: FYI @MrFlick, that method mostly works but drops the `NA` values. An alternative is to use `dplyr::nest_by(training)` which will preserve them.

Comment: `dfZero <- df[df$username %in% key[key$training == 0, "username"],]`

Comment: oops.  gsame is my typo.  They're all supposed to be gsamse

Comment: @Skaqqs Honestly I like this approach better than the other one that creates a list.  Do you want to make it an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%in%`

```
dfZero <- df[df$Username %in% key[key$training == 0, "username"],]
dfOne <- df[df$Username %in% key[key$training == 1, "username"],]
```

Using `merge()`

```
dfZero <- merge(df, key[key$training == 0,], by.x = "Username", by.y = "username")
dfOne <- merge(df, key[key$training == 1,], by.x = "Username", by.y = "username")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dflist <- merge(df, key, by.x = "Username", by.y = "username") %>%
  unique() %>%
  group_by(training) %>%
  group_split()
```

edit: You can extract the individual list elements like so:

```
dfzero <- dflist[[1]]
dfone <- dflist[[2]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly question because i'm sure this pretty much works, but I can't figure out how to then get these data frames out of the list.  I've found other answers like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169631/split-a-list-into-separate-data-frame-in-r
That explain that, but when I use those solutions my data frames dont have column names anymore.  Would you mind please taking your answer one step further to actually having separate data frames?  I need to ultimately use write_csv to export them